# Swig wrapper for function with different struct pointer

Tags: python, c, swig

I want to wrap the following C function. Note, the type casting from Foo_t * to Bar_t *:

```
void function(Foo_t * f) {
      Bar_t * b = (Bar_t *) f;  // casting is done in C original code
      //do sth with b
}
```

Swig generates a wrapper that follows this pattern:

```
void wrap_function( Foo_t *foo ) {
     function(foo);
}
```

But In python, I want to call my wrapper function, using a Bar_t instance:

```
b = Bar_t()
function(b)
```

So, I started a the following typemap:

```
%typemap(in) Foo * {
  Bar_t *temp;
  int res0 = 0;
  Foo_t *arg = 0;

  res0 = SWIG_ConvertPtr($input, (void **) &temp, $descriptor(Bar_t *), 0|0);
    if (!SWIG_IsOK(res0)) {
        SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res0), "in method '" "function" "', argument " "1"" of type '" "Bar_t *""'"); 
    } 
     $1 = (Foo_t *) temp;
     function(arg);
}
```

But the exception is thrown!

How can I cast from Bar_t * to Foo_t * ?

Comment: Accessing through a pointer of a different type is undefined behaviour.  Use C++ if you need inheritance.

Comment: If the alignment requirements are the same for Foo * and Bar *, I should get the original pointer. I cannot modify the C code side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a typemap to expect a Python Bar_t wrapper for a Foo* input, you won't be able to pass a Foo* to a Foo* input.  Instead, export a cast helper.  Note the `%inline` notation both implements and exports a wrapper for the content.

**test.h**

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#   ifdef EXPORT
#       define API __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define API __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef struct Foo {
    int a;
} Foo_t;

typedef struct Bar {
    int b;
} Bar_t;

API void function(Foo_t * f);
```

**test.c**

```
#define EXPORT
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

API void function(Foo_t * f) {
      Bar_t * b = (Bar_t *) f;  // casting is done in C original code
      // do something with b
}
```

**test.i**

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%inline %{
Foo_t* Foo_cast(Bar_t* bar) {
    return (Foo_t*)bar;
}
%}

%include "test.h"
```

**Testing:**

```
>>> import test
>>> bar = test.Bar_t()
>>> test.function(test.Foo_cast(bar))
>>> foo = test.Foo_t()
>>> test.function(foo)
>>>
```